# JSP (expression language) not working in java based configuration spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, el

I have followed the steps on [this tutorial](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-helloworld-tutorial-annotation-javaconfig-full-example/) and made my own project. This is what I have so far:

The project's structure

[image]

pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nicu</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaBasedConfig</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JavaBasedConfig Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>JavaBasedConfig</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>JavaBasedConfig</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

HelloWorldConfiguration

```
package com.nicu.javaBasedConfig.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.nicu.javaBasedConfig")
public class HelloWorldConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

HelloWorldInitializer

```
package com.nicu.javaBasedConfig.configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class HelloWorldInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { HelloWorldConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

HelloWorldController

```
package com.nicu.javaBasedConfig.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "uop");
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloagain", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHelloAgain(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "uop uop");
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>HelloWorld page</title>
</head>
<body>
    Greeting : ${greeting}
</body>
</html>
```

The project is working fine, I can access localhost:[port]/JavaBasedConfig but the jsp is not displayed correctly. As you can see below, I get the exact code from the jsp file.

[image]

Comment: add `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

Comment: @JuneyoungOh Yeah, it's working. Can't believe I missed smth so basic. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`
close the question and Thanks :D b

Answer (score 1):

Along with core jstl taglib, activate the jsp Expression language in your jsp.
Use following code in your jsp file: 
`<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>`

Comment: This was asked and answered two years ago.

Comment: siva, thanks for your answer. It resolved my issue.